# How can I use MUI breakpoints to show an image depending on the screen size?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a task which is to show an image depending on the size of the screen. If the screen size changes, the image size changes too.
So for doing that, I have to use MUI breakpoints. I'm new to MUI and I find their explanation quite difficult to apply. So Can anyone help me with the breakpoints?
This is my code:

```
interface EmptyStateProps {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  handleOnClick: () => void;
  buttonText: string;
  picture: string;
}

export const EmptyState = ({ title, description, handleOnClick, buttonText }: EmptyStateProps): ReactElement =>{
  const { buyingTheme } = useBuyingTheme();
  const isDark = buyingTheme.palette.mode === 'dark';

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={buyingTheme}>
      <Box display='flex' width='100%' justifyContent='center' alignItems='center'>
        <Box display='flex' sx={{ height:'445px', width:'445px', border: '1px solid red' }}>
          <Box
            height='306px'
            width='333px'
            sx={{
              paddingTop: '70px',
              paddingBottom: '70px',
              paddingRight: '70px',
              paddingLeft: '47px',
              backgroundImage: `url(${isDark ? './picture.png' : './pictureLight.png' })`,
              backgroundPosition: 'center',
              backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
              backgroundSize: 'contain', //like obect-fit
            }}
          />
        </Box>
        <Box display='flex' flexDirection='column' alignItems='left' sx={{ height:'136px', width:'445px', border: '1px solid blue', marginLeft: '20px' }}>
          <Typography variant="headings.h3" sx={{ height:'24px', paddingTop:'4px', paddingBottom:'4px' }}>{title}</Typography>
          <Typography
            variant="body.default"
            color="text.secondary"
            sx={{
              whiteSpace: 'pre-line',
              wordWrap: 'break-word',
              marginTop: '4px', height:'48px',
              paddingBottom:'4px', marginBottom: '4px',
            }}
          >
            {description}
          </Typography>
          <Button
            sx={{ height: '40px', width: '93px', padding:'20px', marginTop: 'auto' }}
            onClick={handleOnClick}
          >
            {buttonText}
          </Button>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </ThemeProvider>
    );
 }
   ;
```

so I have two image sizes for two screen sizes
image 1--> height='306px' and width='333px'
screen size--> widht:1920px and height: 1080px

image 2--> height='285px'and   width='285px'
screen size--> widht:1280px and height: 832px

So how can i render one image or the other depending on the screen sizes?

Comment: I assume it's the `backgroundImage` you are looking to change? (Also, you could remove a lot of the unrelated code from your example to make this question clearer)

Comment: Yes, it is the backgrpundImage. Do you know how to it?

Answer (score 1):

The breakpoints are used within the `sx` prop as an object like so:

```
<Box
  height='306px'
  width='333px'
  sx={{
    backgroundImage: {
      xs: `url(${isDark ? './pictureXS.png' : './pictureLightXS.png' })`,
      md: `url(${isDark ? './pictureMD.png' : './pictureLightMD.png' })`,
      lg: `url(${isDark ? './pictureLG.png' : './pictureLightLG.png' })`,
    },
    ...
  }}
/>
```

You can use the default breakpoints (xs, sm, md, lg, xl) at their default values, or you can customise the breakpoint values/names within your `createTheme` setup.